# jPlayer stutters looped video in FireFox

Tags: jplayer

I have an mp4 video with an animation cut in such a way that when looped would not show a break.  When I ask jPlayer in Chrome to do this, it works fine, but in FireFox it pauses itself for about a 1/3 second before re-playing the loop.

So I tried to have the video play itself over again when it gets to the last 1/2 of a second.  I added a 1/2 second to the end of the video that matches the first 1/2 second, and when the jPlayer timeUpdate event determined that we where in the last 1/2 second it would call play with a start time that would match it up with the position it was at (0 + (0.5 - timeLeft)).  Once again, Chrome did this well and while a bit better of a match, Firefox failed to render a perfect loop.

Is this something mythical with the current state of web browsers, or am I missing something?

```
function buildJPlayerMotions(video_name) {
  return function readyVideo() {
    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
      m4v: "/assets/videos/" + video_name +".mp4",
    });
  };
}



function loadMotionsJplayer(id) {
  $('#' + id).jPlayer({
    ready: buildJPlayerMotions(id),
    swfPath: "/assets",
    supplied: "m4v",
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
    size: { width: '728px',
            height: '402px'},
    timeupdate: function(){
                  var currTime = $('#' + id).data().jPlayer.status.currentTime;
                  var movieLength = $('#' + id).data().jPlayer.status.duration;
                  var timeRemaining = movieLength - currTime;
                  if (timeRemaining < 0.5) {
                    $('#' + id).jPlayer("pause");
                    $('#' + id).jPlayer("play", 0 + (0.5 - timeRemaining));
                  }
                }
 });
}
```